# Setting up PouchDB to Sync Gateway Walrus replication

Tags: ionic-framework, couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'm having a hard time setting up the replication between PouchDB and Sync Gateway.

I tried to follow Couchbase's [blog post](http://blog.couchbase.com/first-steps-with-pouchdb--sync-gateway-todomvc-todolite), but I wasn't successfull, either.

I'm building an Ionic application with [angular-pouchdb](https://angular-pouchdb.github.io/angular-pouchdb/) and [ng-pouchdb](https://github.com/danielzen/ng-pouchdb).

Here's what I got figured out so far:

1. every time I call [`pouchCollection`](https://github.com/danielzen/ng-pouchdb/blob/master/ng-pouchdb-collection.js) it either creates a new database with the given name, or gives you a reference of the already created database;
2. the Sync Gateway is responsible for authorization of each document. I'm running it now with the `GUEST` user enabled, with `"admin_channels": ["*"]`, so everyone should be able to access everything, right?
3. `CORS` should be enable, since both the app and the server are running on the same machine (`localhost`)
4. to get replication in both ways, I should use `db.sync(URL)` (`angular-pouchdb`), where URL is something like `http://localhost:4984/prospect/` (and `prospect` could be the DB name)

Here's my Sync Gateway `config.json` file:

```
{
  "log": ["CRUD", "REST+", "Access"],
  "facebook": {"register": true},
  "CORS": {
    "Origin": ["http://localhost:8100"],
    "LoginOrigin": ["http://localhost:8100"],
    "Headers": ["Content-Type"],
    "MaxAge": 17280000
  },
  "databases": {
    "prospect": {
      "server": "walrus:",
      "users": {
        "GUEST": {"disabled": false, "admin_channels": ["*"]}
      },
      "sync":
      `
      function(doc, oldDoc) {
        channel("everything");
      }
      `
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my Ionic code:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, pouchCollection) {
  $scope.students = pouchCollection('students');
  var URL = 'http://localhost:4984/prospect/';
  $scope.students.$db.replicate.sync(URL);
// ...list the array in the view
}
```

Whenever I try to make the replication work, I get the following in the console when running for the first time:

```
GET http://localhost:4984/prospect/_local/jeOaLtKGemQWDpNAPzorJQ%3D%3D?_nonce=1442271117949 404 (Not Found)xhRequest @ pouchdb.js:641625.module.exports @ pouchdb.js:6435ajax @ pouchdb.js:604824.module.exports @ pouchdb.js:6211ajax @ pouchdb.js:989(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:994ajaxPromise @ pouchdb.js:993(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:1241(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:1069979 @ pouchdb.js:10760(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:7659(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:764679 @ pouchdb.js:1076068.Checkpointer.getCheckpoint @ pouchdb.js:9407(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:10076
pouchdb.js:6416 GET http://localhost:4984/prospect/_local/2_QcxPjLD.zmtOXa7VM8Gw%3D%3D?_nonce=1442271117953 404 (Not Found)xhRequest @ pouchdb.js:641625.module.exports @ pouchdb.js:6435ajax @ pouchdb.js:604824.module.exports @ pouchdb.js:6211ajax @ pouchdb.js:989(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:994ajaxPromise @ pouchdb.js:993(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:1241(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:1069979 @ pouchdb.js:10760(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:7659(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:764679 @ pouchdb.js:10760(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:9408
pouchdb.js:6416 GET http://localhost:4984/prospect/_local/jeOaLtKGemQWDpNAPzorJQ%3D%3D?_nonce=1442271118095 404 (Not Found)xhRequest @ pouchdb.js:641625.module.exports @ pouchdb.js:6435ajax @ pouchdb.js:604824.module.exports @ pouchdb.js:6211ajax @ pouchdb.js:989(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:994ajaxPromise @ pouchdb.js:993(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:1241(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:1069979 @ pouchdb.js:10760(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:7659(anonymous function) @ pouchdb.js:764679 @ pouchdb.js:10760updateCheckpoint @ pouchdb.js:930368.Checkpointer.updateTarget @ pouchdb.js:936868.Checkpointer.writeCheckpoint @ pouchdb.js:9362finishBatch @ pouchdb.js:9829
(index):28 The above 404 is totally normal. PouchDB is just checking if a remote checkpoint exists.
```

Since the last line says it is normal, I assume everything is fine.

```
When I run the app in the browser and in the emulator, Sync Gateway says things like:
2015-09-14T19:54:04.913-03:00 HTTP:  #001: GET /prospect/?_nonce=1442271244612
2015-09-14T19:54:18.730-03:00 HTTP:  #002: GET /prospect/?_nonce=1442271258729
...
2015-09-14T19:56:13.362-03:00 HTTP:  #049: GET /prospect/_local/2_QcxPjLD.zmtOXa7VM8Gw==?_nonce=1442271373356
2015-09-14T19:56:13.376-03:00 HTTP:  #050: PUT /prospect/_local/2_QcxPjLD.zmtOXa7VM8Gw==
```

To me, it looks like everything is working. But I can't get it to sync with the iOS emulator or in a different browser.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by 'different browser'?  What are you using?

Comment: You seem to be getting successful responses, maybe it is on your client side?  May you post your iOS code to see why you cannot get it to sync with the emulator?

Comment: @sweetiewill: Actually, I'm using the Ionic framework. By 'different browser' I mean trying to sync between Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @sweetiewill Done: added Ionic code sample. As far as I could see, the `db.changes` from the `ng-pouchdb` library works correctly. I put a breakpoint there, but it didn't get called when I tried to sync stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your Questions..

[2]: The * Star channel is the channel where every document is automatically added to that channel.  Example, a guest user will be granted the * star channel where that gives you the open ended access so any user that gets * (star) will be able to see everything in the system.

[3]: You do not need to enable CORS as sync gateway is running on the same domain as your webapp.  Enabling CORS allows web apps to access resources on other domains rather than the origin domain.

The `LoginOrigin` list protects access to the `_session` and `_facebook` endpoints.

[4]: To replicate your data, within the `app.js` file you would define a URL variable for sync, like:

```
var SYNC_GATEWAY_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:4984/prospect/';
```

Comment: [2]: So, if I add anything anywhere, the `"*"` channel will see it, right?
[3]: Thanks, I'll dig deeper on it =]

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get the constant error message go away? I'm constantly getting error 
GET Http://localhost:4984/mybucket/_local/4jm_8Z70bAx9pah9QrJraw%3D%3D?&_nonce=1448873712726 404 (Not Found)
Is this normal, it creates a lot of error log and why this is not found?

Comment: I have found that I get an _bulk_get error whenever I refresh the window and the local PouchDB object is recreated and tries to synchronize and I get a remote checkpoint error whenever the database is destroyed and then recreated (and tries to synchronize)... but in both cases, it is not fatal as long as the downstream workflow is designed to wait for the promise to complete.